# Having Issue in formatting the data of Recyclerview

Tags: android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am new Android and working on a project in which I have an API which gives me values like SymbolName (Ex: GOLD),BID,ASK etc.
So I have called this api in a Recyclerview.
The user can add new symbol as the user adds a new symbol it is passed in the API and We get the details of the symbol.
The data is shown properly, but I want to change the text color of Bid and Ask which is received from API.
So for example when i call the API BID value is 5, so it will display in blue color. After an interval of 1 second or so I will call this API again and if the new Value received from API is lower than the previous Value than the text color should change to red or it will be Blue if it is greater.
I have written the code for it and its working fine until there are only 5 Symbols, If i pass the 6th Symbol in the API the logic does not works the same.

For your reference I am attaching the code.

My Fragment Quotes in which I need to call

```
public class Quotes extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

LinearLayout bottomlayout,v1,v2;
EditText search;
TextView cancel;
ArrayList<QuoteData> quotelist = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> SYSMBOL_ARRAY = new ArrayList<>();
RecyclerView recyclerView;
QuoteAdapter adapter;
ProgressBar progressBar;
SwitchCompat proview,onclicktrade;

DatabaseHelper mydb;
ArrayList<String> list;
String symbollist = "";
String usersymbol;
String value;

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

boolean REFRESH_SYSMBOL = false;
Intent mIntent;
static BroadcastReceiverData mBroadcastReceiver;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the popup for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quotes, container, false);

    sharedPreferences = this.getContext().getSharedPreferences("switch",MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    mydb = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());

    list = mydb.getValues("Symbol_Table");
    String val = "";
    String symbolname = "";

    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "List"+list.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        val = list.get(i);

        if (val.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            symbolname = val ;
        }
        else
        {
            symbolname = symbolname +"," + val ;
        }
    }

    value = symbolname.replace(" ","%20");

    usersymbol = Dataholder.url + value;

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.lists);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    adapter = new QuoteAdapter(getActivity(),quotelist);

    ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new SimpleDragHelper(adapter);
    ItemTouchHelper touchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
    touchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(),R.drawable.item_decorator)));


    new QuotesData().execute("http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/mobileapp-webservice/new/Default.aspx?Action=getDashboardT&token="+usersymbol+"&from=1&to=20");
    return view;
}

class QuotesData extends AsyncTask < String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return Dataholder.getApi(urls[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        SYSMBOL_ARRAY.clear();
        quotelist.clear();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            String auth = jsonObject.getString("result");
            JSONArray jsonArray =new JSONArray(auth);

            for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject key = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                if (key.getString("message").equals("success"))
                {
                    String symbol = key.getString("symbol");
                    String bid = key.getString("bid");
                    String bidqty = key.getString("bidqty");
                    String ask = key.getString("ask");
                    String askqty = key.getString("askqty");
                    String ltp = key.getString("ltp");
                    String open = key.getString("open");
                    String close = key.getString("close");
                    String high = key.getString("high");
                    String low = key.getString("low");
                    String vol = key.getString("vol");
                    String oi = key.getString("oi");
                    String change = key.getString("change");
                    String netchange = key.getString("netchange");
                    String lotsize = key.getString("lotsize");
                    String ltt = key.getString("ltt");
                    String lut = key.getString("lut");
                    String expiry = key.getString("expiry");
                    String exchange = key.getString("exchange");

                    SYSMBOL_ARRAY.add(symbol);
                    quotelist.add(new QuoteData(symbol,bid,bidqty,ask,askqty,ltp,open,close,high,low,vol,oi,change,netchange,lotsize,ltt,lut,expiry,exchange));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    REFRESH_SYSMBOL = true;
                }
                else if (key.getString("message").equals("fail")) {
                    quotelist.clear();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (REFRESH_SYSMBOL) {

            mIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ServiceQuote.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("keyWatchUrl", "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/mobileapp-webservice/new/Default.aspx?Action=getDashboardT&token="+usersymbol+"&from=1&to=20");
            getActivity().startService(mIntent);

            try {
                mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiverData();
                IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Dataholder.ACTION_ACTIVE_QUOTE);
                intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                getActivity().registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void setQuotefirst(String result){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        String auth = jsonObject.getString("result");
        JSONArray jsonArray =new JSONArray(auth);

        for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject key = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            if (key.getString("message").equals("success"))
            {
                String symbol = key.getString("symbol");
                String bid = key.getString("bid");
                String bidqty = key.getString("bidqty");
                String ask = key.getString("ask");
                String askqty = key.getString("askqty");
                String ltp = key.getString("ltp");
                String open = key.getString("open");
                String close = key.getString("close");
                String high = key.getString("high");
                String low = key.getString("low");
                String vol = key.getString("vol");
                String oi = key.getString("oi");
                String change = key.getString("change");
                String netchange = key.getString("netchange");
                String lotsize = key.getString("lotsize");
                String ltt = key.getString("ltt");
                String lut = key.getString("lut");
                String expiry = key.getString("expiry");
                String exchange = key.getString("exchange");

                for(int j=0;j<SYSMBOL_ARRAY.size();j++){
                    if (SYSMBOL_ARRAY.get(j).equalsIgnoreCase(symbol)){

                        quotelist.remove(j);
                        quotelist.add(j,new QuoteData(symbol, bid, ask, high, low, lut));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Handler handlerRefresh = new Handler();
public class BroadcastReceiverData extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context,final Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Dataholder.ACTION_ACTIVE_QUOTE)){
            handlerRefresh.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String data = intent.getStringExtra(Dataholder.ACTION_KEY);
                    setQuotefirst(data);
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
}
```

Adapter Code of RecyclerView 
Here is the logic of Comparing and RED/BLUE color is Displayed

```
public class QuoteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <QuoteAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
Context context;
List<QuoteData> data;

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView time,symbol,sellmax,selllow,buymax,buylow,buy,sell,spread,lowtext,hightext;
    LinearLayout layout,layoutbid,layoutask;

    double currentbid,lastbid,currentask,lastask;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVTime);
        symbol = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVSymbol);
        sellmax = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVSELLMAX);
        selllow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVSELLLOW);
        buymax = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVBUYMAX);
        buylow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVBUYHIGH);
        buy = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVBUY);
        sell = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVSELL);
        spread = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVSpread1);
        lowtext = itemView.findViewById(R.id.low);
        hightext = itemView.findViewById(R.id.high);
        layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        layoutbid = itemView.findViewById(R.id.LLBid);
        layoutask = itemView.findViewById(R.id.LLAsk);
    }
}

public QuoteAdapter(Context context,List<QuoteData> data)
{
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.quotelist,viewGroup,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}


@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {
    final QuoteData data1 = data.get(i);

    if (i % 2 == 1) {
        myViewHolder.layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fff0f0f0"));
    } else
    {
        myViewHolder.layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }


    Spannable bid = new SpannableString(data1.dBid);
    bid.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.7f),2,3,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    Spannable ask = new SpannableString(data1.dAsk);
    ask.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.7f),2,3,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    myViewHolder.time.setText(data1.dLut);
    myViewHolder.symbol.setText(data1.dSymbol);
    myViewHolder.sellmax.setText(data1.dBid);  //Bid
    myViewHolder.selllow.setText(data1.dLow);
    myViewHolder.buymax.setText(data1.dAsk);  //ask
    myViewHolder.buylow.setText(data1.dHigh);


    myViewHolder.currentbid = Double.parseDouble(data1.dBid);
    myViewHolder.currentask = Double.parseDouble(data1.dAsk);



    if (myViewHolder.currentbid > myViewHolder.lastbid)
    {
        myViewHolder.sellmax.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }else if (myViewHolder.currentbid < myViewHolder.lastbid)
    {
        myViewHolder.sellmax.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }

    myViewHolder.lastbid = myViewHolder.currentbid;
    //myViewHolder.lastask = myViewHolder.currentask;




    myViewHolder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context); // Context, this, etc.
            dialog.setTitle("Action");
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.tradeaction);
            dialog.show();

            TextView trade = dialog.findViewById(R.id.TVTrade);
            TextView chart = dialog.findViewById(R.id.TVChart);
            TextView detail = dialog.findViewById(R.id.TVDetail);

            detail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent detail = new Intent(context,DetailSymbol.class);
                    Bundle symbol = new Bundle();
                    symbol.putString("symbol",data1.dSymbol);
                    detail.putExtras(symbol);
                    context.startActivity(detail);
                }
            });

            chart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Dataholder.Chart = true;
                    Intent chart = new Intent(context,MainScreen.class);
                    context.startActivity(chart);
                }
            });

            trade.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent trade = new Intent(context,tradeitem.class);
                    Bundle symbol = new Bundle();
                    symbol.putString("lotsize",data1.dLotsize);
                    symbol.putString("symbol",data1.dSymbol);
                    trade.putExtras(symbol);
                    if (mBroadcastReceiver != null){
                        context.unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
                    }
                    context.startActivity(trade);
                }
            });

        }
    });
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}
}
```

Class to store data of API

```
public class QuoteData {

public String datasymbol;
public String dataltp;
public String datachg;
public String datavol;

public QuoteData(String txtsymbol, String txtltp, String txtchg){
    this.datasymbol = txtsymbol;
    this.dataltp = txtltp;
    this.datachg = txtchg;
}


String dSymbol,dBid,dBidqty,dAsk,dLtp,dAskqty,dOpen,dClose,dHigh,dLow,dVol,dOi,dChange,dNetchange,dLotsize,dLtt,dLut,dExpiry,dExchange;
public QuoteData(String dSymbol, String dBid, String dBidqty, String dAsk,String dLtp, String dAskqty,String dOpen,String dClose,String dHigh,String dLow,String dVol,String dOi,String dChange,String dNetchange,String dLotsize,String dLtt,String dLut,String dExpiry,String dExchange){
    this.dSymbol = dSymbol;
    this.dBid = dBid;
    this.dBidqty = dBidqty;
    this.dAsk = dAsk;
    this.dLtp = dLtp;
    this.dAskqty = dAskqty;
    this.dOpen = dOpen;
    this.dClose = dClose;
    this.dHigh = dHigh;
    this.dLow = dLow;
    this.dVol = dVol;
    this.dOi = dOi;
    this.dChange = dChange;
    this.dNetchange = dNetchange;
    this.dLotsize=dLotsize;
    this.dLtt = dLtt;
    this.dLut = dLut;
    this.dExpiry = dExpiry;
    this.dExchange = dExchange;
}

public QuoteData(String dSymbol,String dBid,String dAsk,String dLow,String dHigh,String dLut){
    this.dSymbol = dSymbol;
    this.dBid = dBid;
    this.dAsk = dAsk;
    this.dLow = dLow;
    this.dHigh = dHigh;
    this.dLut = dLut;
}

}
```

So can anyone please help me why is the logic not working when the 6th Symbol is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define two ArrayList of String in Adapter

```
public class QuoteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <QuoteAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

Context context;
List<QuoteData> data;
List<String> olddatabid = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> newdatabid = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> olddataask = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> newdataask = new ArrayList<String>();

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

TextView time,symbol,sellmax,selllow,buymax,buylow,buy,sell,spread,lowtext,hightext;
LinearLayout layout,layoutbid,layoutask;


public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVTime);
    symbol = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVSymbol);
    sellmax = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVSELLMAX);
    selllow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVSELLLOW);
    buymax = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVBUYMAX);
    buylow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVBUYHIGH);
    buy = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVBUY);
    sell = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVSELL);
    spread = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVSpread1);
    lowtext = itemView.findViewById(R.id.low);
    hightext = itemView.findViewById(R.id.high);
    layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
    layoutbid = itemView.findViewById(R.id.LLBid);
    layoutask = itemView.findViewById(R.id.LLAsk);
}
}

public QuoteAdapter(Context context,List<QuoteData> data)
{
   this.data = data;
   this.context = context;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.quotelist,viewGroup,false);
return new MyViewHolder(view);
}


@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {
    final QuoteData data1 = data.get(i);

myViewHolder.time.setText(data1.dLut);
myViewHolder.symbol.setText(data1.dSymbol);
myViewHolder.sellmax.setText(data1.dBid);  //Bid
myViewHolder.selllow.setText(data1.dLow);
myViewHolder.buymax.setText(data1.dAsk);  //ask
myViewHolder.buylow.setText(data1.dHigh);

if (newdatabid.size()< data.size())
{
    newdatabid.add(data1.dBid);  //Insert Value in array for the first time
}

if (olddatabid.size()< data.size())
{
    olddatabid.add(data1.dBid);  //Insert Value in array for the first time
}



if (newdataask.size()< data.size())
{
    newdataask.add(data1.dAsk);   //Insert Value in array for the first time
}

if (olddataask.size()< data.size())    //Insert Value in array for the first time
{
    olddataask.add(data1.dAsk);
}





newdatabid.set(i,data1.dBid);   //Store Value in array
newdataask.set(i,data1.dAsk);   //Store Value in array

//Compare and perform Logic
if (Float.valueOf(newdatabid.get(i)) > Float.valueOf(olddatabid.get(i)))
{
    myViewHolder.sellmax.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
}

if (Float.valueOf(newdatabid.get(i)) < Float.valueOf(olddatabid.get(i)))
{
    myViewHolder.sellmax.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}



if (Float.valueOf(newdataask.get(i)) > Float.valueOf(olddataask.get(i)))
{
    myViewHolder.buymax.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
}

if (Float.valueOf(newdataask.get(i)) < Float.valueOf(olddataask.get(i)))
{
    myViewHolder.buymax.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}


olddatabid.set(i,newdatabid.get(i));
olddataask.set(i,newdataask.get(i));

        }
    });
}
 }


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
 }
}
```